# Discord.js - Creating an Array to Dump Image Files

Tags: arrays, discord.js

I am currently hosting a Discord.js bot, and have hit a snag whilst creating a command. I already have in place a command that uses a predefined array to select a random photo to send to the text channel (See code below). However, I wanted to know how to create a command that dumps all of the images using the values found in the array.
Could anyone help me out?

P.S. The code found below only includes the array and the command I already have, and I can provide more code if needed. However, I only found these bits necessary.

```
const haidaArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76' '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83'];

if(command === `${prefix}haida`) {
    let haidaResult = haidaArray[(Math.random() * haidaArray.length) | 0];

    message.channel.send({files: [`./haida/${haidaResult}.jpg`]});

    console.log(chalk.bgMagenta('[fun]') + ' ' + message.author.username + ' requested: ' + command);

    return;
}
```

Comment: You can not embed multiple files in one message. You will need to send a separate message for each image

Comment: @Monacraft I do understand that, however, I needed a process to do so. That was more my problem than anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a for loop.

First you should count the array. You do this with `ARRAY.lenght`. After that it's a simple for loop. So after it sends one picture it checks if the length is lower then `i`. If yes the loop is over:

```
const haidaArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76' '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83'];

if(command === `${prefix}haida`) {
    let haidaResult = haidaArray[(Math.random() * haidaArray.length) | 0];

    for (var i = 0; i < haidaArray.length; i++) {
        //Send your image
        message.channel.send({files: [`./haida/${haidaResult}.jpg`]});
        console.log(chalk.bgMagenta('[fun]') + ' ' + message.author.username + ' requested: ' + command);
    }
return;
}
```

And also you don't want to log your message 80 times so i would just send it after the for loop and not in the for loop.

Have fun coding :D